# Diferencia entre PHP y Node.js

Tags: php, nodejs

Se que obviamente los dos son diferentes, que PHP es un lenguaje de programación totalmente aparte de Node, pero me gustaría saber cuales son sus similitudes y sus diferencias, ya que hace poco escuche que Node era ''una plataforma para Javascript en el lado del servidor'' y supongo que PHP es un lenguaje de programación y no una ''plataforma'', así que si alguien pudiera explicarme la diferencia entre estos dos estaría muy agradecido.

Comment: Hola Ricardo, creo que estás usando incorrectamente el sitio al solicitar opiniones o explicaciones. Es mejor que uses un buscador como Google para investigar lo que quieres y en este lugar hacer preguntas específicas y concretas sobre algún problema de programación. Consulta el Centro de Ayuda si deseas más información.

Answer (score 2):

esto puede ser un tema bastante largo pero lo principal que podemos diferenciar es que `php` es un lenguaje y `nodejs` no lo es, `nodejs` es como lo has dicho una plataforma realizada apartir de c++ (por medio del motor v8 de google) el cual interpreta archivos con el lenguaje `javascript` para "x" actividad, ya que aunque fue creado para web se utiliza para diferentes actividades por su simplicidad.
ahora `php` también es interpretado (no me acuerdo cual era su lenguaje si no estoy seguro es `foltran`) pero corre ya en un servidor siendo `apache` su principal aliado.
por que es una plataforma `nodejs`, es por el hecho que añade funciones propias para extender el uso del lenguaje y facilitar a la hora del desarrollo.
este puede ser un tema muy largo pero en este momento no puedo responderte con mas (tengo que dormir), espero que este poquito te ayude en algo.

Comment: PHP está hecho en c.